# Data frame group by and find a value in a new data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame and I have to see if there exists an entry where for every marketplace there is last_saturday data which is also a maximum data entry.

```
data = {
        'marketplace': [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4],
        'date': ['2017-11-11', '2017-11-10', '2017-11-07', '2017-11-08', '2017-11-10', '2017-11-09', '2017-11-10']
       }
last_saturday = '2017-11-11'

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['marketplace', 'date'])

df_sub = df.groupby(['marketplace'])['date'].max()
print(df_sub)
```

I get `df_sub =`

```
marketplace
3    2017-11-11
4    2017-11-10
5    2017-11-10
Name: date, dtype: object
```

How can I iterate through `df_sub` to see if the date for a marketplace matches `last_saturday`?

When I try to print out the dates `print(df_sub['date'])` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 83, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 141, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: 'date'
```

I assume that in order to access data in `df_sub` I have to use `iloc` or `loc` but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need compare `Series` with value only - get boolean mask and need [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True`:

```
print ((df_sub == last_saturday).any())
True

print (df_sub == last_saturday)
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

---

Or create `DataFrame` first by parameter `as_index=False` or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_sub = df.groupby(['marketplace'], as_index=False)['date'].max()
#df_sub = df.groupby(['marketplace'])['date'].max().reset_index()
print(df_sub)
   marketplace        date
0            3  2017-11-11
1            4  2017-11-10
2            5  2017-11-10
```

And compare column:

```
print ((df_sub['date'] == last_saturday).any())
True
```